# How to make multiple http requests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an HTTP request in my parent and child controller:

**Parent controller**

```
//Product is a $resource object that return http request as a promise.
Product.getItem()
   .then(function(items) {
      $scope.items = items
      //do something in the parent controller.
})
```

**Child controller**

```
Product.getItem()
   .then(function(items) {          
      $scope.items = items
      //do something in the child controller
})
```

**Product Factory**

```
angular.module('testApp').factory('Product', function($http,$q) {
    var service = {}
    service.getItem = function() {
        return http.$get('api/url');
    }
    return service; 
})
```

Child controller is launched when I am in certain pages. The problem is when I launch those pages, the codes will make double http request to api/url because parent and child controllers both make the requests. Although my app still works, I was wondering if there is a better way to solve it. thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you just do some validation on $scope.items?
if(!$scope.items) {Product.getItem()...}

Comment: no because $scope.items is always going to be undefined when the page first loads because it's via http request.

Comment: If the **Child controller** is truly a child of **Parent controller**, then it will inherit the parent scope, thus inheriting `$scope.items`.

Comment: if its undefined when the page first loads you want it to get...

Comment: @Phil it's true if I set the static value to $scope.items like $scope.items = 'test'; I console.log($scope.items) and it returns 'test' but not the http request value

Comment: That entirely depends on when `console.log` runs. Why don't you add a watch on child controller's `items` and see what happens. See http://plnkr.co/edit/zqfpraii9GhLwlw8hDMq?p=preview for an example (don't forget to open your console)

Comment: @Phil Thanks, it does show inside the $watch function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
I investigated Phil's comments a bit, and fixed (rewrote) my example.  The plunker at the bottom reflects these changes.  Here is the updated code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, getStore) {
  getStore.get().then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data
  })
});
app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, getStore) {
  $timeout(function() {
    getStore.get().then(function(data) {
      $scope.test = data
    })
  },3000)

});

app.factory('getStore', function($http, $q) {
  var self = this;
  var data;
  return {
    get: function() {
      if (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('already got data')
        return $q.when(data)
      } else {
        data = $http.get('test.json')
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log('fetched data')
          return response.data;
        })
        return data
      }
    }
  }
})
```

---

Here is one solution - separate your $http.get to a factory and store the value there.  Factories are singletons, so both controllers can access and check the data.

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, getStore) {
  $scope.data = getStore.get()
});
app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, getStore) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.data = getStore.get()
    var check = getStore.checkData();
    console.log('Data in store: ' + angular.toJson(check));

  },1000)
  $scope.getData = function() {
    console.log(getStore.get());
  }
});

app.factory('getStore', function($http) {
  var self = this;
  return {
    data: undefined,
    get: function() {
      if (self.data) {
        console.log('already got data')
        return self.data
      } else {
        $http.get('test.json')
        .success(function(data) {
          console.log('no data found');
          self.data = data;
          console.log(self.data);
          return self.data;
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

It just runs a check to see whether the value is already stored or not, and then returns it if it is, and if not, it gets, stores, and returns it.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jgFpUDb2xQbCw2n2Jyqo?p=preview)

Comment: I see your point. Your codes work if all logics to process the returned data are in child controller. What if I need to do something to returned data in the Main Ctrl. Thanks and +1

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: For example, app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, getStore) {
  $scope.data = getStore.get() 
  I need to do something to $scope.data}); in your main ctrl

Comment: oh i see...You mean like modify it and then you want the child controller to get the modified data?

Comment: yeah, I need to modify the data in the main ctrl and display them and also needs to modify the data in child controller and display them.

Comment: just add a setter method to the factory `setter: function(data) {self.data = data}`

When you modify the data, call the setter function.  If you need the child controller to update it's current data to the freshest data whenever it changes, you could look at some other solutions, such as setting a $watch on the data.  You could also broadcast changes, since they are parent/child controller.  There are a few ways you could do it.

Comment: You should really wrap the pre-loaded data in a promise for a consistent API. For example `if(self.data) return $q.when(self.data)`. You should also return the `$http` promise as the `return` statements in the `success` callback won't be returning to anything external.

Comment: @Phil - I set it up that way for demonstration purposes.  I would normally just return the $http.get call.  
I'm not seeing the problem with the return though.  If it was 'this.data' it wouldn't return anything external, so I set self to refer to the factory object.

Comment: Check your plunker. For one, it doesn't work and two, even without the syntax errors, `$scope.data` in the main controller will remain undefined because you don't return anything in the `else` block.

Comment: @Phil - please see if that is more what you had in mind.