# Redirect to another view by a post id, not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am receiving an external object from WordPress, in one view I have the `post.title`, and if you click in that title you can go to another view and see te entire `post.content`.

So far, I can not see the entire post because I am getting a couple errors, posts is undefined.

I made a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KlfmqW2eLDdEhf90Dsuy?p=preview), [CodePen](http://codepen.io/maketroli/pen/LVGOwO?editors=101) and one [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/libotacoxu/1/edit?html,js,console,output) for you to understand easier. If you use JSBin is better because you can use the console which is integrated there. All you have to do is click on the title of the post, and you are going to realize that can not go to the other view.

Here is the code regarding my issue, which is the same you will see in the online editors I post above

```
.state('tabs', {
  url: "/tabs",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "tabs.html"
})
.state('tabs.news', {
  url: "/news",
  views: {
    'tab-news': {
      templateUrl: "tab-news.html",
      controller: 'NewsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tabs.post-detail', {
  url: '/news/:postId',
  views: {
    'tab-news': {
      templateUrl: 'tab-post-detail.html',
      controller: 'PostDetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

the html for the main view, news

```
<a ng-href="#/tabs/news/{{post.ID}}">
   <h2 ng-bind-html="post.title"></h2>
   <p>{{post.date | date}}</p>
</a>
```

and here is the view where you can not enter yet, the view where are redirected after clicking in the title on the main view

```
<div>
  <h3>{{:: post.title}}</h3>
  <p>{{:: post.content}}</p>
</div>
```

now the controller for the main view

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, FreshlyPressed) {
  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $scope.posts = FreshlyPressed.getBlogs($scope);
  }
});
```

here the service

```
angular.module('urbanet.app.service', [])

.service('FreshlyPressed', function($http) {
  return {
    getBlogs: function($scope) {
      $scope.posts = [];
      $http.jsonp('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/freshly-pressed?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .success(function(result) {
          $scope.posts = result.posts;
        });
    },

    get: function(postId, $scope) {
      console.log(postId);
      console.log($scope.posts);
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.posts.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.posts[i].id === parseInt(postId)) {
          return $scope.posts[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
})
```

and controller for the second view, the view of the entire post

```
.controller('PostDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, FreshlyPressed) {
  $scope.post = FreshlyPressed.get($stateParams.postId, $scope);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to make a new request for individual posts

The `freshly-pressed` api returns to you a `siteID` and `postId`. 
You then combine those to use the `posts` API to get the single post.

Since `freshly-pressed` is a constantly changing list, this is the only way you would ever be able to bookmark posts. Tomorrow you may not get the same set of main posts, so wouldn't be able to replicate links that were used today the way you are attempting to

Service method:

```
getPostById: function(siteId,postId ) {
  var url ='https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/'+siteId+'/posts/'+postId+'?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
  return $http.jsonp(url)
}
```

controller

```
.controller('PostDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, FreshlyPressed) {
  var postId = $stateParams.postId,
      siteId = $stateParams.siteId;

 FreshlyPressed.getPostById(siteId,postId).success(function(response){        
    $scope.post = response
  })
});
```

Modify links accordingly

```
<a ng-href="#/tabs/news/{{post.site_ID}}/{{post.ID}}">
```

[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/CiZBXcwDGcOXUxlOduar?p=preview)

Comment: should go back through your service and get rid of the scope being passed and use this same approach for getBlogs()

Comment: I really need to learn more about Angular. The same happens when my boss is with me, I have only one solution for every single thing, but he gets around 4 different solutions for the same problem. Sometimes I feel very stupid. Thanks again

Comment: Not just about angular but mapping out how you want to get data. I've never seen that API...had to poke around to even understand what `freshly-pressed` was. Thought it was a single blog at first

Comment: also note...you don't need `jsonp`...I confirmed api works fine using json...better error handling ability that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
.controller('PostDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, FreshlyPressed) {
  $scope.post = FreshlyPressed.get($stateParams.postId, $scope);
});
```

This is a problem.  You are trying to pass the entire $scope object as a parameter?

What exactly do you want to pass to the get call?

You have this:

```
get: function(postId, $scope) {  //<- that shouldn't be $scope, make it 'post' or something
      console.log(postId);
      console.log($scope.posts); //Notice that this comes back undefined?
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.posts.length; i++) { //<- length throws an error because there isn't anything there.
        if ($scope.posts[i].id === parseInt(postId)) {
          return $scope.posts[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
```

You shouldn't be trying to pass $scope as a param to your service then access $scope inside the factory.

Have your service store your posts data and return that data to your controllers.  You can do something like this:
[How to make multiple http requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115767/how-to-make-multiple-http-requests/30116476?noredirect=1#comment48344288_30116476)

Don't try to pass in $scope.  Just send the post id to the service and return the data you need.

Comment: I am very confuse actually. I've been with this for the last 2 hours and still can get the logic.

Comment: The controller scope is a new instance and has no `$scope.posts` in it...so `get()` in service won't work as it is now

Comment: still getting the same error, and posts or $scope.posts is still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As [**@tpie**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4427534/tpie) and [**@charlietfl**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) already mentioned, the current approach (passing `$scope` as parameter to the service) doesn't work. Another alternative to what tpie suggested (caching the `posts` data in the service) might be using `resolve` and promises:

**Service code**

```
.service('FreshlyPressed', function($q, $http) {
  return {
    getBlogs: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.jsonp('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/freshly-pressed?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .success(function(result) {
          deferred.resolve(result.posts);
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    },

    get: function (postId, posts) { 
      /* snipped, this wasn't the problematic part */ 
    }
  }
})
```

This won't cache the `posts` result in your service, which might be a downside if the `$http` call you are making is heavy, but using promises is a nice way of setting up asynchronous requests.

Then corresponding **state config**

```
.state('tabs', {
  url: "/tabs",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "tabs.html"
})
.state('tabs.news', {
  url: "/news",
  views: {
    'tab-news': {
      templateUrl: "tab-news.html",
      controller: 'NewsCtrl'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    posts: function (FreshlyPressed) {
      return FreshlyPressed.getBlogs();
    }
  }
})
.state('tabs.post-detail', {
  url: '/news/:postId',
  views: {
    'tab-news': {
      templateUrl: 'tab-post-detail.html',
      controller: 'PostDetailCtrl'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    posts: function (FreshlyPressed) {
      return FreshlyPressed.getBlogs();
    }
  }
})
```

This will invoke the `getBlogs` function in your service **and** wait for the promise to be resolved. After that, you can inject the resolved `posts` variable into your controllers:

and finally **controllers**

```
.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, FreshlyPressed, posts) {
  $scope.posts = posts;
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    FreshlyPressed.getBlogs()
      .then(function (posts) {
        $scope.posts = posts;
      });
  }
});
```

Here we can set up the `$scope.posts` variable directly using the resolved `posts` variable. The `doRefresh` function needs then to be modified so that it will invoke the service function and after the promise is resolved, set the `$scope.posts` data accordingly.

```
.controller('PostDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, FreshlyPressed, posts) {
  $scope.post = FreshlyPressed.get($stateParams.postId, posts);
});
```

And here we give the service `get` function the resolved `posts` variable as parameter, as in this case the service isn't caching that data.

This isn't problem-free approach, for example consider following scenario: you get one set of `posts` data into your main controller. Then, there are new posts posted into the wordpress you are querying, before your user clicks on a title. This might cause the `PostDetailCtrl` to receive a new set of `posts` data, that doesn't any longer contain the certain post that your user clicked.

I think this is anyway a viable alternative, and at least a bit of food for thought.

Comment: problem is though, user can never bookmark url to full post this way since the main feed will change and it relies on that post being in the main feed at all times. Using a permalink to a post though that will never change is far more ideal

Comment: Yeah, that's true - didn't realize it until I read your answer, as I was writing my own when you had posted yours, and didn't take a look myself at the `freshly-pressed` at all.